# Error: "Verify final result code for completed build operation" -- compiles in Xcode 4, not in Xcode 5

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have some code that builds in Xcode 4.6, but does not in Xcode 5. I need to update an app that's in the App Store, but as you all know, we can only use Xcode 5 with iOS 7 SDK now.

I have a workspace with 5 projects in it, each of which successfully builds individually as I change the schemes -- all except the main workspace. So, my assumption is that it's in settings and compiler flags rather than code. I now get an error that says:

"Verify final result code for completed build operation" followed by

"Build operation failed without specifying any errors. Individual build tasks may have failed for unknown reasons. Some of these (up to 12) may be listed below."

None of the "up to 12" reasons, however, are listed below. That's it. That's the error.

I've tried things that others have mentioned around the 'net (checking/unchecking pre-compiled headers PCH, removing DerivedData, rebooting), but have not yet been successful at building. I am using the iOS 7 SDK and targeting either iOS 4.3 or 5.1 (I've tried both) due to wanting to keep code compatibility. This error provides no direction for focus, nor explains why it builds in Xcode 4.6 (which we can no longer use to submit app updates) but not on Xcode 5.  Please HELP!

Comment: Have you tried targeting to iOS7, just to see if it compiles?

Comment: @Antoinio, yes I've tried targeting it to iOS versions 7, 6.1, 6.0, 5.1, 5.0 and 4.3 and have the same result.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10773483/148357) help? If not, does a build folder cleanup (option + product menu) help? Do you perhaps have any 3rd party library that's not compatible with ios7?

Comment: The Product | Clean succeeds, but then doesn't build normally. I am checking all of the libraries, and will update in a little while.

Comment: You can try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/24527851/2759361 .It perfectly works on XCode 5

Comment: Having too many files and folders in the directory or sub-directories of where the project or workspace is located can cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with this problem, and solved it by moving the project file to a much shorter path. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/71124