# What causes "clang failed with exit code 255" in Xcode IDE?

Tags: ios, xcode

Other users have asked about "clang exit code 255" before, such as in this post:

[Xcode not compiling any project? 'clang failed with exit code 255'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023563/xcode-not-compiling-any-project-clang-failed-with-exit-code-255)

I know how to fix the error. This usually does it:

- Clean the project
- Go to 'Window > Organizer > Project > Delete Derived Data'
- Restart Xcode
- Fixed, like magic...

However, I don't know what causes it, and lately, it's been happening a lot (which is frustrating because it's time consuming).

Anyone know what causes this error and how to prevent it from happening?

Comment: Usually this has to do with having too many running processes on the device because xCode didn't cleanly stop them which leads to zombie processes. Are you using ARC?

Comment: "Too many running processes" - as in, too many processes that were started by my app and not terminated correctly by Xcode on stopping the simulator?

Comment: Ya, I mean, I don't exactly know the cause, but I know it has something to do with zombie processes due to xCode not cleaning properly. When it has happened to me, it's been when I am running into a lot of crashes, and trying to debug them.

Comment: I've had this happen (repeatedly, but seemingly without a discernable pattern) after I've pulled in changes via Git and tried to build a project (such as if changes were made in a static library added as a submodule). I don't think its necessarily related to having a static library in a project though, as I've had it happen on most projects I've worked on....?

Comment: Are you working in the most recent xCode version? And also which OSX are you on. I guess I only ask because I haven't had that issue in a while and figure it was just something they worked out in more recent versions. As far as your static library, I would think that if they are doing something funky that isn't being killed properly, then that could be messing you up

Comment: Yes, I'm on the latest Xcode version: 4.5.2. I'm using Mountain Lion: 10.8.2. I've seen others speculate that this may be caused by Xcode running into the "per user process limit". I'm going to dig some more and see if I can verify that this is the case, or if perhaps someone answers that can either verify such or provide another solid explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Closing and restarting the simulator usually clears this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think it also happens when you rename the project in the running state, then XCode will show the project is now missing and it will show the alert with options "Close" and "Resave". If you chose Close then your Derive Data will possesses older name in the path. So, when you try to execute the project next time, it refers to the older path and fails because in that path older name is existing not the new one. So when you clear the Derive Data or restarts the Simulator, the cache files get removed and it runs like a fresh copy.